# "Bon/bonne chance!": spelling and loanword specifics?

Tags: loanwords, french

The adjective **bon** crossed over the Channel "in phrases such as *bon apétit* (1860), literally "good appetite;" *bon-ton* (1744) "good style;" *bon mot*." ([*Online Etymology Dictionary*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=bon&allowed_in_frame=0)) Also with *bon*, *bon-accord*, [*bon(-)vivant*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=bon%20vivant&allowed_in_frame=0), [*bon voyage*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=bon%20voyage&allowed_in_frame=0) etc.

The *OED1(NED)* refers to the "*[bon](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/979/mode/1up), [bone](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/984/mode/1up), [BOON](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/994/mode/1up) q.v.*" form. Then the *boon* (b*ū*n) entry says used especially with originally French phrases. So you had *bone* (and *bonne* as a variant), like in *bone chere*, and *bone fortune*. Yet after the 16th, the NED explains the form was mostly dropped.

*Books* yields [**ngrams**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bon%20chance%2Cbonne%20chance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbon%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbonne%20chance%3B%2Cc0) for both *bon/bonne chance*; the former, similar to the earlier phrases (i.e. *bon voyage*), and the latter, spelled like in the source language and sometimes appearing in quotation marks in the output. The pronunciation of *bon* can vary ([bɒn, bɔn, bɔːn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bon?s=t)), and overlap that of the noun [bonne](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bonne?s=t) (/bɔn/, i.e. the maid).

---

- Do you write *bon chance* or *bonne chance*? Does the modern *OED* carry/reference/distinguish either? Is it sufficiently in use to say?
- Is *bon chance* a partial borrowing, a semantic [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque), an example of *phono-semantic matching* in loanword translation? How does borrowing generally deal with the peculiarities of the source language, such as [*grammatical gender*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender)?

---

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bon+chance%2Cbonne+chance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbon%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbonne%20chance%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Anecdotally, I've never seen it written as *bonne-chance, voyage, apétit* et. al, despite Jim's ngram indicating that it's the more common variant. Also, I don't really feel *bon*/*bonne* has separately entered vernacular English, but even if it had, gender would only be further bastardized/removed. Enough English is written and spoken incomplete application of its own rules of grammar that expecting any regularity or respect of foreign loaned grammar is wishful thinking.

Comment: For a more widespread example, consider café and résumé, both apparently loaned from around the 18th century and both 'correct' English spellings with and without accents. The pronunciation, one would have to assume, is at least as varied as the spellings.

Comment: Since *chance* is feminine in French, *bonne chance* is correct. And I've certainly seen it spelled correctly more often than I've seen *bon chance*, so I think you might as well spell it right. People who don't know French probably won't notice the difference, and you won't irritate those who do.

Comment: Apparently "[bon chance](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16350/6881)," while incorrect, has become something of a meme for French speakers themselves in imitation of foreign mispronunciations of French.

Comment: Further information from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin#Main_patterns_of_influence): "_Terms that most recently entered the English language have kept French pronunciation and spelling, though this may change with time._". Contrary to what I thought the recent trend seems to be the integral loan. In one instance there seems to be an impact from the feminine form entering the language first  i.e. homme fatal**e**, so maybe this explains in part _bon_ competing with the integral form _bonne_?

Answer (score 1):

Bonne chance. I agree with Peter Shor: if we want to use someone else's language, I think we should do it the proper way, which means their way. I love both English and French and - whatever any book says - I think we should never use a masculine adjective with a feminine noun.

Comment: Thank you! But then, does that mean that "bonne chance" is just an import of a foreign expression as opposed to being integrated i.e. would you use it directly without quotation marks in a text in English? Is it as integrated as something like [_bon appe/étit_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_app%C3%A9tit)? Why is it _bon chance_ appears in published work? Is it because enunciation is pretty much the same whether it's spelled one way or the other?

Comment: I would not use quotation marks with "bonne chance", as I wouldn't with "bon appetit" (accents - I believe - are less important in another language which doesn't use them): it is an imported expression, but I now consider good English (I wouldn't say that for bon chance ...), as I consider "sport" an Italian word, even though it is English, really. Same as "football": you will never see it with quotation marks in Italian. You would not use quotation marks with "Martini", would you?

Answer (score 1):

Living as I do on the border with Quebec, and working daily within it's lovely confines... I'd get a can 'o whoopass handed to me if I were to butcher their language with "Bon chance" ! lol.

If you borrow a foreign phrase - much as if you borrow my lawnmower - you should return it undamaged!

Comment: Thank you! You're under duress so it doesn't count lol. But then, does that mean that "bonne chance" is just an import of a foreign expression (despite bilingualism!) as opposed to being integrated i.e. would you use it directly without quotation marks in a text in English? Is it as integrated as something like [_bon appe/étit_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_app%C3%A9tit)? Why is it _bon chance_ appears in published work? Is it because enunciation is pretty much the same whether it's spelled one way or the other?

Comment: Having English speakers (or editors) mess up the gender of an imported expression is hardly surprising - especially when the phonetic difference is subtle unless you really know a language's tone. Far easier to miss than the difference between "le" and "la", and yes "bonne chance" as an approximation of "good luck" is not uncommon in Quebec. Now, I'd probably not put it in quotations, but my reference is living in a bilingual region where you often hear conversations bounce back and forth between the languages - sometimes mid-sentance - which I grant is not a common experience for most people.